# Classification using KNN with numeric values

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to matlab. For me the task is to perform data classification on some data set. The given data set consists of numeric values. One thing that bothers me is I have to perfrom all KNN,ANN, SVM. In performing KNN, I faced a problem like how to find the value of K. If it is user defined, from which value we have to start and when to stop it. I will be so thank ful if some one answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as `KNN` is concerned, the value of `K` is decided as the square root of `n` i.e the number of training examples. So if you have 100 training examples the value of `k` should be 10. However, again this is just a rule of thumb.

**Source**: Machine Learning with R by **Brett Lantz**

Answer (score 1):

Each of these models have some metaparameters that have to be found "by hand":

- ANN - number of hidden nodes, learning rate, momentum rate, ...
- SVM - kernel type, C value, gamma (in case of poly/RBF kernel)
- KNN - metric used, vote weighting scheme, K

Correct evaluation has to test **many** combinations of the above, and what is even more important, they should be chosen **by the model itself**. So checking some set of values and selecting the one with greatest score is **methodolicaly wrong**. This is usually done by splitting your training data (after train-test split) into training' and validation, then performing internal testing of parameters (trained on training' data) and selecting the ones which yield best results (on validation data) in order to finally give the whole model resulting score (on the test data).

> from which value we have to start and when to stop it. I will be so thank ful if some one answers my question

KNN is well defined for each natural K starting from 1 and ending on the number of examples. However it is usually tested on K in {1,5,10,15} (just a rule of the thumb, nothing more).